# OpenXml, Word and C#

Tags: c#, openxml

Here is my problem: I'm trying to perform a mail merge using **OpenXml** and **C#**. To do this, I have to create a Word document which has the same number of pages as lines in my data set (My data set is a **CSV file**).

I create a new document, and I'm trying to copy my template on each page of this document. Unfortunately, only the first page has the correct format (my template is copied on it). To copy, I use the `InnerXml` that I'm trying to copy from my template to each page of my new word document.

I know that my problem comes from my instructions, but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
string fileName = @"MyTemplate";
using (WordprocessingDocument pkgDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
{
    pkgDoc.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    var test = (pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.InnerXml);

    string filenamecible = @"@MyNewWordDocument";

    using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filenamecible, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();

        //Create DOM tree for simple document. 

        mainPart.Document = new Document();

        for (int i = 0; i < csvline.Count; i++)
        {
            mainPart.RootElement.InnerXml = test;
            var x = new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page };;
            mainPart.Document.Append(x);
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }

        package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i find the solution if someone got the same problem here is the code :

```
string fileName = @"MyTemplate";
using (WordprocessingDocument pkgDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true))
{
    pkgDoc.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
    var test = (pkgDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.InnerXml);

string filenamecible = @"@MyNewWordDocument";

using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filenamecible, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();

    //Create DOM tree for simple document. 

    mainPart.Document = new Document();

    for (int i = 0; i < csvline.Count; i++)
    {
         var x = new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page };
         Body b = new Body(test);
         mainPart.Document.Append(b);
         mainPart.Document.Append(x);
         mainPart.Document.Save();
    }

    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}

}
```

Comment: What is the problem and what is the solution? You mention neither. You should also use a descriptive title.

Comment: I told in the paragraph . I got a CSV file and i want to create a Word document which contains the same number of pages as number of lines in my CSV file. Moreover, because i'm doing a mailmerge function i had to copy my template Word in each page of the new document. 

My word template is " Hello Mr X , you was born in X ..." the idea was to create a new Word document which contain "Hello Mr X , you was born in X" in each page. The number of page is the same as csv file lines.